# How to get file name in android emulator from default music player?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I want to know how to get the file name of the selected file in music player,In my coding ,i was selected the mp3 file from music player and getting the data from intent and assign it to uri,where i only get the  selected position in music player playlist,like **Path/1** or **Path/2** ,where i was not able to get the FileName of the Mp3 File .kindly help me to solve this one.Here bis my code for Reference

```
//for opening the file
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("audio/mp3");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
                        PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

//Get FileName

```
   String mPath = null;
            Uri mToneCaptureUri;
            mToneCaptureUri = data.getData();               
            mPath = mToneCaptureUri.getPath(); // from File ManagerF
                    setPath(mPath);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting full path and file name

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
```

use this on onActivityResult

```
mpath = getPath(data.getData());
```